# Как сделать flip анимацию?

Tags: android, анимация, android-animation

Вот есть такая статья

https://medium.com/a-problem-like-maria/understanding-android-matrix-transformations-25e028f56dc7

В абзаце `Scaling` сказано(вконце), что

> But there’s more you can do with scaling. If you provide negative scale values you can essentially mirror the image around an axis (or two)

Так же в статье есть пример вращения вокруг оси и как будто выглядит нормально, но когда это делаешь с вью которое больше по размеру (скажем на пол экрана - конейнер какой то), то становиться быть видно как все такие работает scaling который как будто делает эффект flip, но все же остается скейлингом.

Так вот вопрос, как сделать по настоящему `flip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда-то давно мне тоже понадобилось сделать flip-анимацию и на тот момент меня удовлетворило стороннее решение [EasyFlipView](https://github.com/wajahatkarim3/EasyFlipView). Может быть и в вашем случае будет достаточно имплементировать это решение, либо порыться в исходниках и понять как это там реализовано.